# Assigning null to String Literals & GC

Tags: java, string

I want to know if assign null to string literal, will it be eligible for garbage collection or not ?

```
String s = "abc";
s=null;
```

If not how can we achieve so ? Is there any way to clear literal pool ?

Comment: You'd have to unload the class. Because the class has a reference to the string.

Comment: "Is there any way to clear literal pool ?" - no. Why would you need that ?

Comment: Also you aren't assigning null to a string literal in this code.

Comment: @alfasin I think to control the behaviour of GC

Comment: String literals will be GCed if they have no references and the classloader that loaded the classes that defined these literals gets GCed

Comment: @BharatSahu No it won't.

Comment: @EJP Okay, thankyou.. can you explain it?

Comment: @BharatSahu See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if assign null to string literal

There is no way to assign null to a string literal. There is only a way to assign null to a *reference,* which is what your code below is doing.

> will it be eligible for garbage collection or not?

No. It will remain in the constant pool until the class is unloaded.

```
String s = "abc";
s=null;
```

> If not how can we achieve so?

You can't.

> Is there any way to clear literal pool?

No.